# How To Use Structured Table-Referencing in Excel Data-Validation?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I'm attempting to create Data Validation for a column in an Excel table. The validation needs to reference another column in the table.

There are 2 columns, "f1" and "f2". Each column can contain either "Y" or "N".

Using cell-addressing works fine:

[image]

My question is: how to make a validation-formula with structured table-addressing?

Excellent overview of structured-referencing: http://peltiertech.com/structured-referencing-excel-tables/

The desired validation on column "f2" is:

```
=Table1[f1]&Table1[f2]<>"YN"
```

This pic shows the table and validation formula above entered next to the table, showing expected validation results:

[image: Pic1]

I added the above formula into Data Validation --> Custom, for cells in "f2". That fails-- it rejects valid entries (ie entries for which that formula evaluates to True).

Then, I tried creating a defined name using that formula, based on this post, and used that name as my custom validation. That also fails. 
https://superuser.com/a/480660

Then I tried using INDIRECT in my defined name, based on this post:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/10/15/how-to-use-a-table-name-in-data-validation-lists-and-conditional-formatting-formulas/

[image]

[image]

But valid entries still getting rejected.

How to do this?

I think the reason structured-referencing fails in a validation formula is because TableName[FieldName] evaluates to the entire column, not just the current row. Therefor, i'm exploring ways to limit the validation-formula to just the current row.

I thought of these methods so far:

I think that in structured-referencing, the current row is identified with @.

So, the formula would be:

```
Table1[@f1] & Table1[@f2]<>"YN"
```

or

```
Table1[[@[f1]] & Table1[@[f2]]<>"YN"
```

That actually works on sheet, but still does not work as a validation-formula.

My next try was to use INDEX to pull just the current row. The formula is:

```
INDEX(Table1[f1] & Table1[f2],1,0)
```

Again, that works on-sheet, but not as a validation-formula. I think this is a promising direction, though!

Comment: thx, Ralph, but i don't think it's going to help to build my own validation form. The issue is how the formula is being evaluated-- your answer does not address that.

Comment: i understand Ralph. Sure, i can write VBA to compare every single cell, one-at-a-time. But, it would be far easier and simpler to use normal cell addressing (see my addition to the OP) than building a whole new custom form. This thread is asking: how to do it with structured table-addressing?

Comment: The cell reference formula seems to work fine. As you add new rows to the table it will not accept a "YN" combination, in my testing.

Comment: yep, @ScottHoltzman. My question is: how to do it with structured table-referencing, instead of normal cell-referencing.

Comment: @johnywhy - I get that, but I am almost positive it won't work. And cell referencing does the trick, so why not just use that?

Comment: plz see edits to OP. -thx

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, no offense, but let's see if someone can provide a solution. The answer to "why?" is: for the same reason Microsoft created structured referencing for on-sheet formulas: [AutomobileColor] is more meaningful than B:B.

Comment: Do you have to use the table references? If you select cell H2 then enter =E2&F2 as the refers to in your named range you should be able to enter =valInder<>"YN" in the Data Validation

Comment: Hi @ScottHoltzman et al, i solved it. See my answer below (marked as answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The solution is to use a lookup-list for the validation.
- This solution uses real addressing, and does not require `INDIRECT`. You can build the formula on-sheet, if desired, and get address auto-complete.
- This solution uses structured table-referencing.
- As in the question, we have a table-object with 2 columns (named "Col1" and "Col2" in this answer), into which the user may enter "Y" or "N" in either column.
- As in the question, we will accept all combinations *except* "Y N", which will raise a standard data-validation alert.

**Steps**

1. Create 2 named ranges outside of the table-object (can be on a separate, hidden sheet if desired):

   - `rngY`: Y
   - `rngYN`: Y, N
2. Create the following defined-name (note, this formula should not be entered onto the worksheet; it's only in the definition of the defined-name.)

   - "validFmla": `=IF(Table1[@Col1]="Y", rngY, rngYN)`
3. Create the following data-validation in the data-cells of Col2.

   - List-type validation
   - Source: `=validFmla`
   - Optional: uncheck "In-cell dropdown"
4. Done.

[image]

**Result**

- Now, where Col1 contains "N", you may enter "Y" or "N" into Col2.
- Where Col1 contains "Y", you may only enter "Y" into Col2.

[image]

Note, i show the validation formula on the sheet in this image for explanation purposes only-- it's not normally entered onto the sheet for this solution.

It's odd that this works using a pick-list, while the formulas in the original question don't work, but Excel works in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for. You can use INDIRECT formula to reference table in validations.

```
=INDIRECT("TableName[ColumnName]")
```

this will validate data based on the data in the column if List validation is selected.

Comment: Thx for the idea, but that does not achieve my goal: to check the concatenation of 2 columns. These fmla's give correct answer, but don't seem to work for validation: `=INDIRECT("Table1[@Col1]") & INDIRECT("Table1[@Col2]")  <> "YN"`     and     `=Table1[@Col1] & Table1[@Col2]  <> "YN"` It's cool that the `@` points to the current row, so i get auto-complete when typed into a cell, so i don't have to use `INDIRECT` (which is preferable). If i enter these into another col in same table, i get expected `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Note, i put `=INDIRECT("Table1[@Col1]") & INDIRECT("Table1[@Col2]") <> "YN"` into a defined-name, and then put the defined-name into the validation settings, but validation does not reject the "YN" condition, as desired.

Comment: Solved, plz see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

By creating a structured table like this

[image]

Then by referencing using INDIRECT like this:

[image]

BONUS: You can even use double INDIRECT like this. The inside INDIRECT gets you the column headers of the structured table whose named is mentioned in the named ranged TargetTable. The outside INDIRECT return those values for selection by the user. The formula in the first picture is then shoved into the data validation for TargetColumn ranged name using VBA.

[image]

[image]

[image]